# Is it possible to edit web browser images with Python?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, image-manipulation

Is it possible to edit web browser images with Python? Editing means changing pixel data, cropping, scaling.

If so what modules can be used to achieve this. As a newbie, I have briefly looked at PIL and OpenCV but am not sure if these can be used to achieve such a task.

Comment: This would involve two steps: 1) Downloading the image using something like the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library and 2) Editing them with the libraries you already mentioned. Please be more specific with your question, right now it is very broad. Please show us the code you have already written.

Comment: What is "edit web browser images" supposed to mean ?

Comment: Thanks. Edit here means changing pixel data, cropping, scaling etc.

Comment: At the moment I am only working on the algorithm. No code yet. Thanks Maurice.